# How can I find remaing frames in a MediaSource SourceBuffer?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, streaming, mp4, http-live-streaming

I am streaming fragmented MP4 recordings of my screen from a golang server to a SourceBuffer.

Initially the stream is behind 1-2 secs from the screen (1 sec recording + 300-400 ms compressing),
but after 1 minute my stream is 10 secs behind (but the files are still being received after 1-2 seconds).

Let's say I stopped sending files at time 11:30:00, while my stream is at 11:29:50. The video is still going until 11:30:00 and than stops, so the frames for 11:30:00 are in the SourceBuffer.

So how can I get the number of frames/seconds left in the SourceBuffer and where am I now so I can speed up the streaming until I reach almost realtime again.

```
let streamingStarted = false
let queue = []

function onMediaSourceOpen() {
  sourceBuffer = ms.addSourceBuffer(VIDEO_TYPE);

  sourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", () => {
      if (sourceBuffer.updating) {
        return;
      }

      if (queue.length>0) {
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(queue.shift())
      } else {
        streamingStarted = false;
      }
  });
}


webSocket.onmessage = async function(messageEvent) {
    if(!streamingStarted){
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(await messageEvent.data.arrayBuffer());
        streamingStarted = true;
        return
    }
    queue.push(await messageEvent.data.arrayBuffer())
  }
}
```

Update:

Using video and SourceBuffer object I managed to get the number of seconds buffered and speed up the video.

```
if(getBufferedLength() > 0.100) {
    video.playbackRate += 0.11111
    setTimeout(()=> {video.playbackRate -= 0.11111}, 1000)
}
    
let getBufferedLength = () => {
    return sourceBuffer.buffered.end(0) - video.currentTime;
}
```

However the audio lags behind the video this time even though the mp4 files received contains both the video and audio.

Comment: **(1)** _"...How can I get the number of seconds left in the SourceBuffer and where am I now"_ ... See if [activeBuffers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource/activeSourceBuffers) helps you. You could also try `ms.duration` to know total length and also there is `currentTime` from the connected video object. Maybe here is an opportunity to do some simple calculation for any remaining time/frames?

Comment: **(2)** _"...So I can speed up the streaming until I reach almost realtime again"_ not sure what you mean by "speed up" exactly (is it fast forward playback? and why?). The stream stops sending at 11:30:00 but why not let viewers watch normally from their 11:29:50? Or else just skip them to 11:30:00 (in your case this means just stop their stream at 11:29:50 so they miss the other existing 10 seconds)... PS: I think no-one answered you because as currently written the idea sounds like a "not a good user experience". Maybe describe better the viewer's problem to solve when streaming side stops.

Comment: PS: I don't know about your video player's UI but maybe have a seek bar that shows the user (whose time is still 11:29:00...) that there is still some +10 seconds of stream left in front of seeking timeline? This way the user can choose to watch all 10 seconds or just seek within timeline to the most recent time which is zero (for most recent live frames)... Like how Youtube does when you join a livestream after it started (it starts at zero/current time but user can also seek backwards to a previous time and watch with delay until ending)...

Comment: @VC.One Thanks. I managed to find how many seconds are buffered using the video and sourceBuffer objects.